# MySQL Query to set length of all values in column to 12

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a column in a MySQL database which is currently all different lengths an example would be -

```
Reference (Column Name)
12930
1829
892
182902
```

I need them all to be 12 characters long with 0's added to the front to make them that length, so they example above would need to become -

```
Reference (Column Name)
000000012930
000000001829
000000000892
000000182902
```

Is there an SQL query I can run to do this, if not what would the best way to do this be?

Comment: What's the data type of the column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `zerofill` if you use numbers (int, bigint, float etc...)

```
ALTER TABLE a modify column min int(12) /* other properties */ zerofill;
```

if you use varchar or char, you have to use PHP [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
echo str_pad($input, 12, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: +1 for the PHP solution, you don't screw up the mysql data with unwanted zeros.

Answer (score 1):

There is a MySQL function called [`LPAD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) that will do this for you.  Be aware that it will also truncate large numbers by lopping off the lower digits since it treats the field as a string.  Here's an example:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo (n INTEGER);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO foo VALUES (12345), (2147483647);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT n, RPAD(n, 15, ' '), LPAD(n, 5, '0'), LPAD(n, 15, '0') FROM foo;
+------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| n          | RPAD(n, 15, ' ') | LPAD(n, 5, '0') | LPAD(n, 15, '0') |
+------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
|      12345 | 12345            | 12345           | 000000000012345  | 
| 2147483647 | 2147483647       | 21474           | 000002147483647  | 
+------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```